# Why is part of the image hidden

Tags: html, css

Have a look [here](http://dharman.eu/box/index.html).

After you click on a tile a house sprite should get attached to this tile and be shown fully. The image needs to span over several tiles However the sprite is covered by adjacent tiles. Why is that?

```
.div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    cursor: url(house.png) 1 20, pointer;
}
```

Comment: It's covered by the background of the divs to the right and below it

Comment: How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
.div img {
    position : absolute;
}
```

Comment: But I want the image to span over few tiles and not just that one

Comment: Ah give the image `position:absolute;` then

Comment: Genius, can this be achieved using overflow as well?

Comment: It's not an overflow issue since there's no `overflow:hidden` that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the tiles are 20x20px in dimension - this is smaller than your PNG